# drupal search poor - because i also link to external site

Tags: search, drupal-6, full-text-search, external

is there a way to improve my searching of drupal? its 30-50% dont find my content that im sure i put it on the title or somelsewhere in the cck, also i got alot of links , is there a way to tell drupal to fetch the text of the external page and tag it to the node?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look and see if the site is indexed: go to admin/settings/search and check that the site is fully indexed - this happens on cron run (you can run cron manually from the Reports > Status page).

But the main problem is that the basic Drupal search doesn't search CCK fields.  There are other solutions, like using Views or Faceted Search or there is an answer here about using the theme system to expose the CCK fields [How to show CCK field in search result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045775/drupal-how-to-show-cck-field-in-search-result)

As for your 2nd question, not as far as I know, but I'm sure its possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can get text from off site pages, but you can greatly improve your search with the [Fuzzy search](http://drupal.org/project/fuzzysearch) module (allows mispellings and examines cck field values).

After you've got it running be sure to "index" all of your content on the fuzzy search admin page.